# NiFi "routeOnAttribute" race condition

Tags: apache-nifi

In NiFi (which I'm new to), I'm having trouble with a situation where I want to create what I should believe to be a synchronous process.

I have a zip file that is unzipped with UnpackContent processor. There are multiple files zipped up together. One is a JSON file with 'To' and 'CC' email addresses, the other n files are PDFs. I want to make an email using the putEmail processor, with the To/CC addresses coming from the JSON file, and the PDFS attachment to the email. How do I accomplish this? There is a high volume of data coming into these processors very close together in time, so I need to make sure the appropriate JSON with the To/CC addresses contain the pdfs from its respective zip file- currently hacking this by adding a hash before the unzipping process for the merge processor and setting MinNumEntries=2. Do I need to use Notify and Wait processors. My current setup is shown in the text-art graph below, but it has downsides since if there are multiple PDFs, sometimes my last step zipping happens before the JSON is finished processing, which means multiple emails are sent, but some of them are to empty addresses. How do I accomplish this goal, I would think somthing as simple as unzipping, reading some contents, and rezipping then sending as an email could happen synchronously.

```
HashContent=HC
UnpackContent=UC
RouteOnAttribute=RA
EvaluateJasonPath=EP
UpdateAttribute=UA

HC->UC->RA(endswithJSON)->EP->UA->MergeContent
          (endswithPDF)           |
               |                  |  
               V                  |
           MergeContent<-----------
               |
               V
            PutEmail
```